# JPanel overriding revalidate()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

For my program I have a `JPane` that as the game progresses it adds labels to the panel, however the only way I can make the panels show up is by using `add(label)` then revalidating and vice versa for removing labels.

My problem is that once it gets to the point that I have more than 40 labels on the screen the revalidate has to process too many things, so how can I override the `revalidate()`, ether works, so that it only revalidates the specific component that was added, and not every component on the screen. I know there is a loop somewhere within the `revalidate()` method that will run through a loop of all components, but I just can not for the life of me find it. I would like to be able to call `revalidate(component-here)` or `validate (component-here)` and have it only update that specific component.

I know there are other ways of writing this program but I am only interested in how to override `revalidate()` so no "you could have redone your whole code this way which should only take you like 6 hours >.<".

http://www.fileserve.com/file/jFdQ6nv/FINAL_PROJECT.zip a link to my eclipse project, if anyone who wants to help would like to see what im actually talking abouyt

Comment: validate() is in the container class.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820703/261156). Adding 1000 text areas only takes a second, and updates are instant. Labels go even faster. You might want to look at something else slowing it down.

Also, you could look at `CellRendererPane`. It overrides `invalidate()` to do nothing.

```
public void invalidate() {}
```

Comment: in mine it is an asteroids game, so i have lots of lables moving around and shooting and junk

Comment: Sorry, I've only seen asteroids games that draw shapes.